# How to uncache RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I used `cache()` to cache the data in memory but I realized to see the performance without cached data I need to uncache it to remove data from memory:

```
rdd.cache();
//doing some computation
...
rdd.uncache()
```

but I got the error said:

> value uncache is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Float])]

I don't know how to do the uncache then!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

RDD can be **uncached** using `unpersist()`

```
rdd.unpersist()
```

[source](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#removing-data)

Comment: Also, you can pass boolean to unpersist, to determine whether to block until all blocks are deleted or not

Answer (score 12):

The uncache function doesn't exist. I think that you were looking for unpersist. Which according to the Spark [ScalaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) mark the RDD as non-persistent, and remove all blocks for it from memory and disk.

Comment: Thanks you are right. I tried what Josh said and it seems like it's working!

Comment: It's ok. It's exactly the same answer. ;)

Comment: It'd be quite useful to merge the answers and remove one. What do you think?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to remove all the cached RDDs, use this ::

```
for ((k,v) <- sc.getPersistentRDDs) {
  v.unpersist()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you cache the source data in a `RDD` by using `.cache()`
or You have declared small memory.
or the default memory is used and its about 500 MB for me.
and you are running the code again and again,

Then this error occurs.
Try clearing all `RDD` at the end of the code, thus each time the code runs, the `RDD` is created and also cleared from memory.

Do this by using: `RDD_Name.unpersist()`