# Spark 2.3: How to release RDD from memory in iterative algorithm

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Taking an example code from https://livebook.manning.com/book/spark-graphx-in-action/chapter-6/1

```scala
import org.apache.spark.graphx._

def dijkstra[VD](g:Graph[VD,Double], origin:VertexId) = {
    var g2 = g.mapVertices(
        (vid,vd) => (false, if (vid == origin) 0.0 else Double.MaxValue,
            List[VertexId]()))
    for (i <- 1L to g.vertices.count-1) {
        val currentVertexId =
            g2.vertices.filter(!_._2._1) 
                .fold((0L,(false,Double.MaxValue,List[VertexId]())))((a,b) =>
                    if (a._2._2 < b._2._2) a else b)
                ._1
    val newDistances = g2.aggregateMessages[(Double,List[VertexId])]( 
        ctx => if (ctx.srcId == currentVertexId) 
            ctx.sendToDst((
                ctx.srcAttr._2 + ctx.attr,
                ctx.srcAttr._3 :+ ctx.srcId)),
                (a,b) => if (a._1 < b._1) a else b)
    g2 = g2.outerJoinVertices(newDistances)((vid, vd, newSum) => {
        val newSumVal =
            newSum.getOrElse((Double.MaxValue,List[VertexId]())) 
        (vd._1 || vid == currentVertexId,
            math.min(vd._2, newSumVal._1),
            if (vd._2 < newSumVal._1) vd._3 else newSumVal._2)})
    }
    g.outerJoinVertices(g2.vertices)((vid, vd, dist) =>
        (vd, dist.getOrElse((false,Double.MaxValue,List[VertexId]())).productIterator.toList.tail))
}

val myVertices = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(Array((1L, "A"), (2L, "B"), (3L, "C"),
  (4L, "D"), (5L, "E"), (6L, "F"), (7L, "G")))
val myEdges = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(Array(Edge(1L, 2L, 7.0), Edge(1L, 4L, 5.0),
  Edge(2L, 3L, 8.0), Edge(2L, 4L, 9.0), Edge(2L, 5L, 7.0),
  Edge(3L, 5L, 5.0), Edge(4L, 5L, 15.0), Edge(4L, 6L, 6.0),
  Edge(5L, 6L, 8.0), Edge(5L, 7L, 9.0), Edge(6L, 7L, 11.0)))
val myGraph = Graph(myVertices, myEdges)

val result = dijkstra(myGraph, 1L)

result.vertices.map(_._2).collect
```

Every time I run this code, the `VertexRDD` stays in memory and I cannot release it.

[image]

It seems like GraphX is caching the graph data even though it is not specified in the code. Is it possible to release the previous run's RDD data from memory?

I have tried to unpersist by doing `result.unpersist()`, `result.vertices.unpersist()`, `result.edges.unpersist()`, and even `result.checkpoint()`.

Ultimately, I want to run the code in a for loop to find multiple results for different  `origin`, and unless I can figure out how to release the RDDs from before, I come across memory issues.

Update:
A brute force method I came up with to clear all VertexRDD and EdgeRDD

```
for ((k,v) <- spark.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs) {
  val convertedToString = v.toString()
  if (convertedToString.contains("VertexRDD") || convertedToString.contains("EdgeRDD")) {
      v.unpersist()
  }
}
```

Comment: small amount of data. salesman?

Comment: @thebluephantom sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: travelling salesman algorithm? interesting issue

Comment: @thebluephantom the code snippet is dijkstra's shortest path algorithm, I suppose similar to salesman algorithm

Comment: Did notice that but I thought could be variation on

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uncache RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938567/how-to-uncache-rdd)

Comment: @mazaneicha I have tried all the unpersist methods that can be applied to the updated graph but it does not clear the memory. I'm now looking into methods of unpersisting by filtering the unecessary cache using `spark.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs`. 
Edit: Sorry, I just saw the non-accepted answer in your link and it seems like he is trying to approach what I am trying to do now.

Comment: @mazaneicha. i think the point is there is no cache or persist in the code, unless my eyes are bad

Comment: @thebluephantom Yes, correct

Comment: @thebluephantom I'd be surprised if GraphX doesn't cache vertex and edge RDDs internally, especially for the iterative algorithms they use. OP might want to go through the source code to confirm it, but that doesn't change the way those RDDs can be `unpersist()`ed (which the post I referenced shows). Good question nevertheless, upvoted :)

Comment: I've done loops operating on graphx graphs and noticed the same behaviour - the vertex and edge RDDs get cached and stay cached - up until the point that executor memory gets full - then it starts uncaching the previously cached RDDs - seems to be in a FIFO manner - so I guess that unless you are experiencing out of memory errors you could just leave as is like I did

Comment: @mazaneicha. In Spark, RDDs are not persisted in memory by default. To avoid recomputation, they must be explicitly cached when using them multiple times (see the Spark Programming Guide). Graphs in GraphX behave the same way. When using a graph multiple times, make sure to call Graph.cache() on it first.

Comment: probably no issue here, it is small and fits into memory. why not cache if you can keep it in? spark is in memory processing as much as possible

Comment: @RanvirMohanlal I'm trying to find the dijkstra shortest path for set of all of the connected vertices for a graph with ~50 vertices, ~300 edges, and I would come across OOM error. Additionally, the code gets slower and slower to run after each iteration, which I suspect is due to lineage issue. I try to truncate the lineage by `result.checkpoint()` after every run, but it is still slowing down. Have you faced this problem?

Comment: @thebluephantom Looks like vertices and edges are `cache()`ed during `Graph` construction, https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/graphx/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/graphx/impl/GraphImpl.scala#L319. In later releases (2.4.+) StorageLevel is explicitly set to `MEMORY_ONLY`, so that they can be LRU-discarded as others mention.

Comment: By the way, isn't it time to migrate off of Spark 2.3, and from RDD- to Dataframe-based graph implementation? https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/tree/v0.8.1

Comment: But the question is more about lineage I think. The memory only is of course for iterative processing. So we need checkpointing.

Comment: @igeass could you include the looping code here too - maybe there's something in there we could also look at because I'm guessing running the above code once doesn't give you any problems right?